# Random samples and the distribution w.r.t the population

Tags: probability, statistics, sampling

I have read a couple of hours about random sampling and the distribution and I guess that I have figured it out, but I am not 100 % sure. So, maybe one could cross-check my claims :-)

Assume we have a Population $P$ where we are interested in e.g. the body weight per individual.

- We assume that the distribution of the body weight of the population is $W_0$.
- Let $W$ denote the body weight of an individual within this population **(so, $W$ and $W_0$ should be identically distributed, right?)**
- Now, we assume that the observed body weight for the $i$th individual is $W_i$. **Hence, $W_i$ is also a random variable and $W_i$ has the same distribution as $W$ since $W$ is the distribution of an individual of the population, correct?**

The conclusions I draw and where I am not sure about are bold.
Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: The model here is not clear.  You might assume you have $P$ people with i.i.d. weights $\{W_i\}_{i=1}^P$.  Or you might assume you have $P$ people with constant (nonrandom) weights $w_1, ..., w_P$ and you define i.i.d. samples $\{X_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ where each sample $i$  independently and uniformly chooses a person $I_i$ from the population, so $X_i = w_{I_i}$, so that $X_i$ has a common PMF for all $i$.  In the latter case we can re-sample the same person repeatedly, but if the population is large and we only consider a relatively small number of samples, the likelihood of that is small.

Comment: My guess is that if this is a statistics problem, they ultimately want you to assume all samples are i.i.d. according to some unknown distribution that they call the "distribution of the population."  [The two models I have specified above lead exactly to i.i.d. behavior, a third model of sampling fixed weights $w_1, ..., w_P$ *without replacement*  does not lead to i.i.d., but likely they want you to ignore that and approximate it as i.i.d., which is accurate if the number of samples is much less than $P$.]

Comment: You are on the right general track, but I think the test procedure will be clearer if you focus on the _distribution_ from which the $W_i$ are a random sample (independent and identically distributed). Then state the a null hypothesis in terms of the population mean. // See discussion and t test in my Answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might believe that weights in a certain population are normally distributed (weights in pounds), with mean $\mu = 150$ and some unknown standard deviation $\sigma.$ To check this belief you might test
$H_0: \mu = 150$ against $H_a:\mu \ne 150.$

You randomly sample $n = 100$ subjects from  some normal population, obtaining weights $W_i, W_2, \dots W_{100}$
with sample mean $\bar W = \frac 1n \sum_i X_i = 149.65$ and sample standard deviation
$S = \sqrt{\frac{1}{n-1}\sum_i (W_i - \bar W)^2} = 20.05.$

```
stripchart(w, pch="|")
```

[image]

So you didn't get exactly $\bar W = \mu = 150.$
The question is whether, considering the variability
of weights in this population, the difference between $\bar W$ and $\mu = 150$ is due to chance of whether
the difference is 'statistically significant' at the 5% level.

Then you could use a one-sample t test to decide the
issue of statistical significance. In this case,
the tests statistic is $T =  \frac{\bar X - 150}{S/\sqrt{n}} = -0.17681.$

You would reject $H_0$ at the 5% level of significance if $|T| \ge c = 1.984,$
where $T \sim \mathsf{T}(\nu = n-1 = 99),$ Student's
t distribution with 99 degrees of freedom. The critical value $c=1.984$ cuts probability $0.025$ from
the upper tail of the t distribution. [In R, `qt` is the quantile function (inverse CDF) of a t distribution.] We do not reject $H_0$ because $|T|$ is so near the critical value $c.$

> Roughly speaking, a t statistic near $0$ is a way of saying that the sample mean $\bar W$ and the population mean $\mu$ are not remarkably different.

```
qt(.975, 99)
[1] 1.984217
```

Also, the P-value of this test is the probability of a value of $T$ might be more extreme (in a positive or negative directions) than the observed value $-0.177.$
[In R, `pt` is the CDF of a t distribution.] We do not reject $H_0$ at the 5% level because the P-value exceeds $0.05 = 5\%.$

> Roughly speaking, a P-value above 5% is another way of saying that the sample mean $\bar W$ and the population mean $\mu$ are not remarkably different.

```
pt(-0.17681, 99) + 1 - pt(0.17681, 99)
[1] 0.8600188
```

All of this (except for the critical value $c$ of a test at the 5% level), is shown as output to the
procedure `t.test` in R, as follows.

```
t.test(w, mu = 150)

        One Sample t-test

data:  w
t = -0.17681, df = 99, p-value = 0.86
alternative hypothesis: 
  true mean is not equal to 150
95 percent confidence interval:
 145.6676 153.6235
sample estimates:
mean of x 
 149.6455
```

In addition, the output of `t.test` shows a 95%
confidence interval $(145.67,\, 153.62).$ This indicates the $\mu = 150$ (inside the interval) is a believable value of the population mean based on what we see in the sample.

Below is a plot of the density function of the distribution $\mathsf{T}(99).$
The observed value of $T = -0.1768$ is shown as
a solid vertical line. The P-value is twice the
area under the curve to the left of this line. (The dotted vertical line is as far from 0 as the solid one.)

The critical values, $\pm c = \pm 1.984$ are shown
as vertical red dashed lines.

[image]

R code for figure:

```
hdr="Density of T(99)"
curve(dt(x, 99), -4, 4, ylab="PDF", xlab="t",
     col="blue", lwd=2, main=hdr)
 abline(h=0, col="green2")
 abline(v=0, col="green2")
 abline(v = -0.1768, lwd=2)
 abline(v = 0.1768, lty = "dotted")
 abline(v = c(-1.9842,1.9842), col="red", lty="dashed")
```

*Notes:* (1) In case it is of interest, here is R
code used to sample the fictitious data used above:

```
set.seed(411)
w = rnorm(100, 150, 20)
mean(w);  sd(w)
[1] 149.6455
[1] 20.04775
```

(2) In case you had advanced information that
standard deviations of weights in this population
are $\sigma = 20.$ The you could do a z test
instead of a t test.

Some people seem to think
it is OK to do a z test anytime $n > 30,$ using the sample SD $S$ as if it were the same as $\sigma$ (rarely exactly true).
That's a somewhat risky *approximate* procedure.

For my particular fictitious data, it happens that an approximate  z test would
not have led to rejecting $H_0.$ R does not have
a named procedure for z tests. In case it is of interest, I'll show results
from a z test from Minitab statistical software below.

```
One-Sample Z 

Test of μ = 150 vs ≠ 150
The assumed standard deviation = 20

  N    Mean  SE Mean       95% CI           Z      P
100  149.65     2.00  (145.73, 153.57)  -0.17  0.861
```